# Powershell remoting Windows to Linux

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am currently trying to write a Powershell script which will do the following.

1. Connect to Linux machine (SSH)
2. Run commands which generates a file.
3. Get the file to Windows.

I am using Powershell v5.1 and installed OpenSSH but I can't successfully use New-PSSession or Invoke-Command to achieve my goal. I can only connect using ssh command (example: ssh user@linuxmachine).

Any ideas thrown is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you follow the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.1) for this?

Comment: Hi. Yes! aside from the fact that i was using Powershell v5.1. So i wanted to know if there is a way i can go around these other than upgrading my powershell version.

Comment: Nothing that's supported.  As per the documentation:: **_"PowerShell 6 or higher, and SSH must be installed on all computers"_**.  So there _might_ be some hack, but is potentially unstable/limited and not guaranteed to last beyond the next patch.